# how to access aws parameter store value from Nodejs and use it later

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a requirement where I want to access parameter store value and then use that later. This is how I am doing:

```
var options = {
    Name: 'SecretAccessKey_temp',
    WithDecryption: true
};

var secreretAccesKeyParam = ssm.getParameter(options).promise();

secreretAccesKeyParam.then(function (data, err) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else {
        const secretAccessKey = data.Parameter.Value
        console.log(secretAccessKey)
   
       
    }
});
```

This is giving me value but if I want to access **secretAccessKey** variable outside of this it's giving me '**undefined**'. Can anyone please help me out to access this **secretAccessKey** variable outside of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your variable `secreretAccesKeyParam`is a promise, you won't be able to access the context (e.g. `secretAccessKey`) of your promise handler (e.g. `function (data, err) {...}`). By definition of promise doing so :

```
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});
var myRes = 'bar';
myPromise.then(dunction (data, err) {
  myRes = data;
  console.log(myRes); // executed asynchronously
});
console.log(data); // executed sychronously so printed first. myRes value is still 'bar'.
```

Would give you the output :

```
'bar'
'foo'
```

What you might want to do could be using an async function if you want to handle things as if they were synchronous.

```
var options = {
    Name: 'SecretAccessKey_temp',
    WithDecryption: true
};

var secreretAccesKeyParam = ssm.getParameter(options).promise();

(async () => {
  try {
    const data = await secreretAccesKeyParam;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }

  const secretAccessKey = data.Parameter.Value;
  console.log(secretAccessKey);
  ... // any action with your secret access key
})();
```

Or if you are already using handler function later :

```
let _secretAccessKey;
const getSecretAccessKey = async () => {
  if (!_secretAccessKey) {
    try {
      const data = await secreretAccesKeyParam;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
      return null;
    }
    _secretAccessKey = data.Parameter.Value;
  }
  return Promise.resolve(_secretAccessKey);
}

...

async function mySuperHandler() {
  const secretAccessKey = await getSecretAccessKey();
  // do something with the secret
}
```

Comment: In your second example with the SuperHandler, you can return the value in that handler, and this way the usage will be simpler.

Comment: For one handler it is. But this way you avoid code duplication in case you have at least two handlers that needs to access the secret access key. More over I'd say it improve testability by separating the concerns

Answer (score 0):

How about set it as env ?
Im currently use this method, but you have to make sure env is set before use it.

```
secreretAccesKeyParam.then(function (data, err) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else {
    process.env.secretAccessKey = data.Parameter.Value;
    const secretAccessKey = process.env.secretAccessKey;
    console.log(secretAccessKey);
  }
});
```